# Шифровка в php

Tags: php, кодировка

Как то разбирай CMS увидел вот такое,
http://pastebin.com/fDN8Vznw
Глянув версию, более старую:
http://pastebin.com/NJq6xz1K

Да, это ASCII. Или я не прав? 
Но как это дело, можно расшифровать, не по табличке символов...?
И как к этом относиться сам php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP к этому относится положительно. Все это дело называется escape-последовательностями.
Рекомендую прочитать мануал про строки:
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

Comment: Но как же можно их расшифровывать в большом кол-ве

Comment: Хотя бы так:  
http://ideone.com/KiOe6u

Comment: Огромное спасибо, пойду разбирать :)